# Flutter SliverAppBar similar of iPhone Google Maps

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I try to implement in Flutter a similar Google Maps AppBar using CustomScrollView and SliverAppBar with an flexibleSpaceBar, but I don't found any option to display an widget only on "opened" state of AppBar.

The representation of result pretended is this:

[Opened View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dpPD.png)

[Bar View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nc22.png)

After try develop this, I don't have success.

Any idea how to make this?

**UPDATE**

The needed effect is visualized in that gif:

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/feghlEcI1SAPxny7FW)

Answer (score -1):

[image: demo]

Hi, I think you are looking for something like this.

if yes, you can find the code in [flutter gallery app.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_gallery)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I get that example, and try to add more data in expanded view, but I don't have success in it... I have very similar google maps place view design in my application, but i don't understand and don't view in documentation how to construct than... Look at "Opened View" in my question. Sorry any english mistake...

Comment: So you need an Image Slider instead of the single image?

Comment: No, I need more information displayed in expanded state, and that information is hidden in collapsed state.

Comment: I need that effect on scroll up: [iOS Google Maps](https://giphy.com/gifs/feghlEcI1SAPxny7FW)